# Intl.DateTimeFormat 'calendar' and 'numberingSystem' options never work

Tags: javascript, datetime-format

I'm trying to set the `calendar` and `numberingSystem` options for an `Intl.DateTimeFormat` object. When I set them via the `locale` argument as below it works:

```js
var dateFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US-u-ca-chinese-nu-arab');
var usedOptions = dateFormat.resolvedOptions();

console.log("resolved calendar: " + usedOptions.calendar);
console.log("resolved numbering: " + usedOptions.numberingSystem);
```

But when I try to set them via `options` argument as below, it doesn't work. Mozilla MDN [specifically mentions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat) that this should work:

[image]

But when you try it, it doesn't:

```js
var options = {calendar: 'chinese', numberingSystem: 'arab'};
var dateFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default', options);
var usedOptions = dateFormat.resolvedOptions();

console.log("resolved calendar: " + usedOptions.calendar);
console.log("resolved numbering: " + usedOptions.numberingSystem);
```

I have tested this on node.js and Firefox with the same results. Online javascript emulators also give the same result.

I could still set them via the locale string but it's rather ugly. I prefer to use the options argument if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think Mozilla MDN may be wrong about this. If I am reading [the ECMA-402 spec for constructing a `DateTimeFormat`](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-initializedatetimeformat) correctly, in step 8 of §13.1.1 the `calendar` option is considered, but then in step 17 we go to [ResolveLocale](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-resolvelocale) where in step 9.i.iv of §9.2.7 the calendar option only overrides the default if it is already a possible choice for the calendar in that locale.

That said, I cannot seem to come up with a case where it works as I expect it would from reading the spec, so maybe I am reading it wrong. I would expect that the second line here would return `'japanese'`, because the Japanese and Gregorian calendars would be valid choices in the Japanese locale:

```js
> new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ja').resolvedOptions().calendar
'gregory'
> new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ja', { calendar: 'japanese' }).resolvedOptions().calendar
'gregory'
```